# Why is my window.setInterval function overlapping itself in the DOM when called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm attempting to build my own timer which resets back to 7 minutes upon clicking the nextTeam button. However, the timer is overlapping itself upon each call instead of resetting. This causes the timer to flip back and forth between displayed times for each function call.

Any advice for a fix would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="clock"><span id="minutes">7</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span></div>
    <button id="nextTeam"onclick="showNextTeam()" type="button">next team</button>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showNextTeam() {
    clock(7, 0);
}

var clock = function(minutes, seconds) {
    window.setInterval(() => {
        seconds--
        if (seconds < 0) {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        }

        document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = minutes;

        if (seconds < 10) {
            document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = "0" + seconds;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = seconds;
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple intervals running at the same time. When you reset the interval you need to call [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) on the value returned by `setInterval`.  An easy way to do it is to create a variable outside the scope of the functions and save the interval handle there.

```js
let interval;
function showNextTeam() {
    clock(7, 0);
}

var clock = function(minutes, seconds) {
    clearInterval(interval) //clear the old one first
    interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        seconds--
        if (seconds < 0) {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
        }

        document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = minutes;

        if (seconds < 10) {
            document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = "0" + seconds;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = seconds;
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="clock"><span id="minutes">7</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span></div>
    <button id="nextTeam"onclick="showNextTeam()" type="button">next team</button>  
</div>
```